# Double Integral - Variable change Euler

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate 
$$\int_0^1\int_{1-y}^{2-y}\  {\frac 1y}\ e^{-\frac {x}y}\ e^{-y} dxdy$$

I´ve tried $u = -x - y^2$ , $v = \frac{1}{y}$.

Also trying it without variable change and ended up with $\int_0^1e^{1-y}\left(e^{-\frac1y}-e^{-\frac2y}\right)\,dy$.

Answer must be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: can you show your steps too other than your attempts

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you have:

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_{1-y}^{2-y}\frac{1}{y}e^{-\frac{x}{y}}e^{-y}dxdy$.

Then, we can take the antiderivative with respect to $x$, so then we have $\displaystyle \int_{1-y}^{2-y}\  {\frac 1y}\ e^{-\frac {x}y}\ e^{-y} dx=\big{[}-e^{-\frac{x}{y}}e^{-y} \big{]}_{1-y}^{2-y}=e^{1-y}\left(e^{\frac1y}-e^{\frac2y}\right)$.

Then, we have $\displaystyle \int_0^1e^{1-y}\left(e^{-\frac1y}-e^{-\frac2y}\right)\,dy$.

> This integral cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions. However, using $5$ rectangles approximation, the integral is near $0.146$, using $50$ rectangles it's near $0.1493$, using $500$ rectangles it's near $0.1499$, and using $5000$ rectangles it's near $0.150003$.

The integral, using $5,000,000$ rectangles is near $0.15001$.

Comment: Perfect, but, does it mean it cannot be solved by using variable change?

Comment: Well, i cannot see a suitable one, and neither was wolfram alpha, is it didn’t see one in terms of elementary functions...